# События для клонированных элементов

Tags: jquery

Столкнулся с крайне не удобным багом, на клонированные элементы не работает `.hover` . Можно ли как то повесть на них обработчик наведения курсора?

Comment: Как вы вешаете на родительские элементы обработчик? Как клонируете? Дополните ваш вопрос кодом.

Comment: Клонирую через Draggable свойство helper:'clone'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {

  // повесим на элементы .draggable смену фона при hover
  $(".draggable").hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'green');
  }, function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'white');
  });

  // сделаем элементы .draggable перемещаемыми с хелпером clone
  $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    helper: "clone"
  });

  // #droppable сделаем принимающим элементом с обработчиком события drop
  $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        // вставляем клон элемента .draggable. С помощью аргумента true копируются все обработчики и данные клонируемого элемента (см. документацию jQuery)
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone(true));
    }
  });
});
```

[Пример на JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ebomus/2). Перетащите квадрат на прямоугольник (можно несколько раз). Все квадраты в прямоугольнике будут изменять свой фон при наведении мышью.

Comment: @HappyCougar, я трачу время в двух случаях — это принесет пользу большому количеству людей или мне за это платят :) Давайте остановимся на этом варианте, а вы подробнее расскажете, что у вас не получается? Как бы я не водил мышкой - никаких сообщений в консоли по вашему фидлу.

Comment: Ап. Вот вариант проще http://jsfiddle.net/HappyCougar/BApgB/2/ - при клике на итемы с лева - в консоль пишется, если по клону (блок справа) то ничего.

Comment: Советую вам (настоятельно) незамедлительно изучить функцию [$.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Прочитайте всю статью, поймите, как это работает. Это избавит вас от многих дальнейших проблем. Я практически ничего не менял, [только .click на .on](http://jsfiddle.net/BApgB/3/).